# Show modal window using *.nib file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have prefs pane application, and need to show modal window using specific nib file.

I use method:

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"___NibName___" owner:self];
```

It's all right, but window is not modal( I can get access to prefs pane window ).

What should i dot to make this window modal( user should not have acces to prefs pane window, until current window will not be closed ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do and manage afterwards: create a new NSWindowController, set this class as File's owner in your custom nib/xib, connect the window outlet to your window within the nib/xib, get the window reference by first creating an instance of your class and then using

```
NSWindow *window = instance.window;
```

Then run it modal with NSApplication's

```
runModalForWindow:
```

Comment: how can i do this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on `iOS`:

You have to have a separate View Controller to manage that nib file if you want to present it as modal. Once you have an instance of that view controller, present it with this:

```
 aViewControllerClasss *sampleView= [[aViewControllerClasss alloc] initWithNibName:@"___yournibname___" bundle:nil];
 //set any variables of the new view controller(such as delegate) here, before you present it. 
 [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
 [sampleView release];
```

Comment: Oh. He should tag one of the two.

Comment: I agree. I will add a tag for him.

Comment: Thanks, for tag, this question about OSX