# Best design pattern for a window opening another window in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am learning how to create osx applications with Cocoa/Objective-C.  I am writing a simple app which will link together two different tutorials I have been going through.  On start up a choice window loads with 2 buttons,  one button loads one window and the other loads the other window. When either button is clicked the choice window closes.

The choice window controller object was added to the MainMenu.xib file so it is created at launch.  The window is then opened using the awakeFromNib message.

I want the result of one button to open up the 'track controller' tutorial application from the ADC website.  The action looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)trackButton:(id)sender {
    TMTrackController *trackController = [[TMTrackController alloc] init];
    [self.window close];
}
```

I added an init method to the TMTrackController class which looks like this:

```
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self showWindow];
        TMTrack *myTrack = [[TMTrack alloc] init];
        myTrack.volume = 50;
        self.track = myTrack;
        [self updateUserInterface];
        return self;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void) showWindow {
    if(!self.window) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"trackWindow" owner:self];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

I am not sure this is the best way to be doing this as I know that the choiceController class will be released when it is closed thus getting rid of the TMTrackController class too.  However even when I untick the 'release when closed' box of the ChoiceWindow.xib it breaks too.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With xib s in the same project use:

```
@interface    

@property (strong) NSWindowController *test;

@implementation

@synthesize test; 

    test = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"XIB NAME HERE"];
    [test showWindow:self];
    [home close];
```

Comment: where are you putting this code?  In my example the choiceWindowController was creating the new window but here I assume this is somewhere else.

Comment: In my app I have it in an NSObject, and as an IBAction (the `test = [` part)

Comment: I mean, is this in a view controller class or something?  If so, which one, and how do I stop the `test` object being deallocated when the class which created it is released? I can't imagine it's good practice to keep a view controller object in memory after it's got no view to control just to hold onto another view controller!

Comment: No just a standard object. And Im using ARC

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely the same but this is my solution for such problems: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785265/show-modal-window-using-nib-file/10789149#10789149)

Just ignore my statement in this answer regarding showing the window as a modal window. Everything else is still valid. This way you could have your personal window controller and it controls everything there is within the xib. This is a huge advantage for maintaining the project afterwards (and you keep to the application logic).