# Make a XIB window open on button press

Tags: objective-c, window, xib

Really struggling to get this to work. I've declared the window from the xib file as an IBOutlet and am trying to send it 'makeKeyAndOrderFront' but it's just not working. I know there are other questions based on this but they don't seem to help me.
I'm a bit new to all this so sorry if my terminology is off. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use my instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785265/show-modal-window-using-nib-file/10789149#10789149). Last last part about showing the window modal is not useful in your case. Everything else is. If you have problems, please try to describe them exactly. Only then we could help you. Please copy your code below your question so that we can have a look at it.

Everything else is just guessing for everyone.